# How to resolve this error : _.mixin({ (s3_multipart upload gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using http://rubygems.org/gems/s3_multipart to upload multiple upload,
but I've got error when loading the page. just like this

[image: errorjacascript]

https://github.com/maxgillett/s3_multipart/issues/6

So, does anyone know how to resolve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, the `_.function()` syntax is from '[underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/)'.

Have you required the 'underscore.js' library?  The 's3_multipart' gem requires you to have added the following to your 'application.js' file (assuming you're using the 'jquery-rails' and 'underscore-rails' gems):

**app/assets/javascripts/application.js**

```
//= require underscore
//= require jquery
//= require s3_multipart/lib
```

Here's a line from the s3_multipart README.md on Github where he talks about the underscore dependency (https://github.com/maxgillett/s3_multipart):

> If you are using sprockets, add the following to your application.js
>   file. Make sure that the latest underscore and jQuery libraries have
>   been required before this line. Lodash is not supported at this time.